# Translation and meaning of Shukla Yajurveda Madhyandia Shaka Sandhya

Tags: sandhyavandanam, shukla-yajurveda

Sri Animesh Nagar has documented the Shukla Yajurveda Madhyandina Shaka Sandhya prayog in his [blog](https://animeshnagarblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/14/suklayajurveda-sandhyavandana-prayoga/)

I have presented the relevant section below. Can you please help me provide the pronounications in english script and the translation. This will be very useful for people who do want to practice sandhya pryayog.

Also please note that it is difficult to obtain the translated version of the book in South and Maharashtra. The number of Madhyandina Shaka people in MH and South of India is limited.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This he has given actually from a book. The book must’ve derived it from one of the older manuscripts of the sutra. The katyayaniya sutra available today has the process in very very short. It would be very nice if you could also write whether this is found in an older version of the Katyayaniya sutra.

Comment: I had once asked Animesh Nagar why don't you provide Engslish transliterations and translations too? He said that is intentionally done because people are not supposed to learn these rituals from internet. But then I thought what is the purpose of his blog then. But anyway you will get such Prayoga books in your mother tongue in the local markets. We have Bengali prayoga books like RigVedi Sandhya, YajurVedi Sandhya etc. easily available. You can try to purchase such books

Comment: Animesh Nagar is also mostly posting (in his blog) screens from books that he has. So it's not difficult to get these books.

Comment: @Rickross I am currently outside India and is difficult to obtain these books. Also it is difficult to obtain these books in south india and Maharashtra. There are not many Madhyandina shaka people in south and MH

Comment: Oh ok... But you might get manuals in English too if you search on internet. Might not be that difficult I guess,@inpraiseofagni

Comment: @Rickross I am unable to find anything, could you please point me to one if you do find it

Comment: Okay if I find something useful I will inform you in a comment here. @inpraiseofagni

Comment: Thank you @Rickross